# will the code coverage report of data access layer for below dll is zero? if so why?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage

```
var istrxValid= ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL.Setup(post => post.InsertTransaction(dt, transactionItems)).Returns(isValid);
var istrxInsertion = ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL.Object.InsertTransaction(dt, transactionItems);
var controller = new ClosedLoopSyncController(appSettings.Object, ClosedLoopTrxSyncDAL.Object);

SyncDataAnchor result = controller.ClosedLoopSyncService(ClosedLoopTrxList);
```

Here data access layer method will not be invoked when the debugger is in business access layer as im mocking DAL hence will the code coverage for DAL will be covered or not as in my case its showing 0% for DAL

Comment: If you mock the DAL then it will not be executed during test. Then you have covered 0% of you DAL. Or what is your question?

Comment: @Jocke yes i want to confirm that if DAL Layer is mocked then it wont be covered in code coverage report? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, only classes (code) executed by the unit test will count.